# Mount ext4 read-only

Tags: mount, ext4, readonly

This will still write to `/dev/foo` if there is a journal:

```
mount -oro /dev/foo /mnt/disk
```

How can I treat `/dev/foo` as read-only?

Comment: The question may make sense to you, but you should explain the issue for others (including google). Such as "The ext4 journal is automatically replayed on mount, how can I prevent this, and all other writes to the underlying device". The title is also misleading, as the filesystem is read only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
mount -oro,noload /dev/foo /mnt/disk
```

Comment: You should explain the answer, and what the option does.

Comment: This helped me when I had to mount a newer ext4 filesystem with an older mount, etc. that didn't understand some of the modern journal options. The `noload` option seems to disable the journal, though it's essentially undocumented. The `mount(8)` man-page mentions it under the docs for `--read-only` but says nothing about what it actually does. :/

Answer (score 3):

If you make the device readonly first:

```
blockdev --setro /dev/foo
```

then the filesystem will be unable to write to it, so you don't need to know any special type-dependent filesystem options.

Comment: blockdev is only able to block rw access from userspace. There still can be rw access to a device even if set ro using blockdev. See also https://lkml.org/lkml/2007/2/6/1 and other references online.