# Mounting a bad raw disk image without fixing it?

Tags: mount, dd, fdisk, disk-image

Is it possible to mount a bad disk image without fixing it? Here's the story why.

I was playing around with dd, and I accidentally wrote back a 20GB virtual disk image onto the disk itself. The old ext4 file system is obviously trashed, I have a 20G GPT partition (EFI, swap and btrfs root) visible on the disk and nothing else.

I made a raw image of the disk and I would like to try recovering data from it. My first attempt would be to re-make the GPT partition setup on it with default settings, maybe that would help. But I want to do it on the image, not the disk itself. But for that, I need to mount it first. Now, I receive the following message on attempt:

```
mount: mount(2) system call failed: Structure needs cleaning.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mount ext4 read-only](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/337638/mount-ext4-read-only)

Comment: It gives the same result: structure needs cleaning. I also want write access to re-make the partition and file system.

Comment: Hold on, I've just realised what you're trying to do. `mount` mounts a filesystem, not a disk. You might want `losetup`, but mostly just treat the image as if it were a disk device. So run `parted disk.img`, etc